# Finding the Taylor Series Approximation of $\sin(x)$ at $x=\pi/4$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I'm trying to find a Taylor series approximation for $\sin(x)$ at $\pi/4$.

Simply going through the derivatives, I get:
\begin{align}
f(\pi/4) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
f'(\pi/4) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
f''(\pi/4) &= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
f^{(3)}(\pi/4) &= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
f^{(4)}(\pi/4) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{align}
Using the Taylor series approximation formula (http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/c/3/a/c3a379aaf2b04999084373279ed2da10.png), do I simply sub in pi/4 wherever I see an a?

WolframAlpha solved it like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOzHZ.png so I'm probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Your calculation is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You've calculated the derivatives correctly; so yes, you would just substitute in $\frac{\pi}4$ wherever you see an $a$. This would yield, as the start of the sum:
$$\sin(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{x-a}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{(x-a)^2}{\sqrt{2}\cdot 2!}-\frac{(x-a)^3}{\sqrt{2}\cdot 3!}+\frac{(x-a)^4}{\sqrt{2}\cdot 4!}+\ldots$$
What Wolfram|Alpha is doing is, to get the proper alternation of signs in the terms (i.e. +, +, -, -, +, +, -, -, ...) is using the term $\sqrt{2}\sin(\frac{1}4(\pi+2n\pi))$ (though it cancelled the $\sqrt{2}$ with the one in the denominator of your expansion) which, as $n$ increases yields the sequence $1$, $1$, $-1$, $-1$, $1$, $1$, \ldots

Comment: Thanks! How would I sum it while keeping the sequence of alternating positive and negative terms? As you can see the 1st and 2nd terms are posiive and the 3rd and 4th are negative.

Comment: @user I just added that; so, to be really explicit, we get the proper alternation of signs by multiplying the factor $\sqrt{2}\sin(\frac{1}4(\pi+2n\pi))$ to each term, which gives:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{2}\sin(\frac{1}4(\pi+2n\pi))(x-\frac{\pi}4)^n}{\sqrt{2}\cdot n!}$$
The fact that this works follows from that $\sin'(x)=\sin(x+\frac{\pi}2)$ - an alternate way to write the derivative. (If you cancel the $\sqrt{2}$, then this is just using that $\sin^{(n)}(x)=\sin(x+\frac{n\pi}2)$)